# Intranet Domain name without domain

Tags: dns, intranet

We have an internal webserver, I made a user on this server (Openlogic 6.6, Centos Web Panel installed).

the domain : testnet.company.local
In the dns I have a record testnet which resolves to the ip of the server.

In a browser when you go to "http://testnet.company.local/application" it works.

But if I want users to be able to go to testnet/application or just to "http://application" what are the steps I need to take? Is this possible? Our DNS server is a Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Do the users have a common search list on their machines? I don't suggest using barewords as DNS names without some serious investigation.

However, say, for example, that all of your users have company.local in their searchlist. You can then add "testnet" to the company.local DNS zone and it will resolve because the user's machines will automatically add "company.local" to the request.